# Getting text following a label in XPath

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do some tests using Selenium and I am facing some problems. Suppose I have the following:

```
<div class="itemize-row">                                              
  <p class="subText">
    <span class="item-label">Card Color:</span> Mandarin
    <span class="item-label">Colored Mug:</span> Red
  </p>
</div>
```

Could anybody tell me how to retrieve data "Red" using XPath or CSS?

Comment: What selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: @alecxe,Thank You,I'm using Java

Comment: @khanam - Do you want to retrieve "Red" as data or you want to retrieve data in span element?

Comment: @OarpitO,i would like to retrieve value of Colored Mug.i.e., "Red",please do the needful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//span[@class='item-label' and .='Colored Mug:']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

will return `"Red"` as requested.

---

> Generally speaking, yes, but in Selenium, you cannot point to the text
>   nodes. XPath expressions have to point to "elements". – alecxe

Ok, to account for Selenium limitations, this XPath,

```
substring-after(//span[@class='item-label' and .='Colored Mug:']/.., 'Colored Mug:')
```

which takes advantage of the fact that your target is at the end of the string value of the parent of the label, will also return `"Red"` as requested.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, but in Selenium, you cannot point to the text nodes. XPath expressions have to point to "elements".

Comment: This gives error "unable to locate element" when trying to use it from selenium.

Comment: @alecxe:  Ugh.  Assuming Selenium can deal with string values, I've added another XPath for OP to use that leverages the fact that the target is at the end of the string value of the parent of the label.